# Where can I find information about conventions used in Oracle's Java documentation?

Tags: java, documentation, conventions

I'm relatively new to Java, and still run across methods I've never seen before when perusing the Java documentation. I sometimes get confused about the right way to use the methods because I don't know the conventions used by Oracle.

Consider this example from the [String class page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
contains(CharSequence s) 
Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
```

I wondered:

Is `CharSequence` a literal value? 
Does it represent that the variable `s` has to be a `CharSequence`? 
What's the proper syntax for using this method?

While clarified after further digging, I feel I could have narrowed my search considerably if I'd known of some kind of meta-documentation. It'd be great if there were a document somewhere that says "We always use representative data in our examples", or "literals are always bolded" or "variables which you are presumed to have already defined are always italicized".

For instance, in the example above, *I* would have presented it thusly for clarity:

```
contains(s) 
where s is a user-defined variable of type CharSequence 
Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
```

I've been unsuccessful in finding anything that documents the documentation, and most of my searches return results about JavaDoc. I'd love a link if someone knows about it.

Comment: Your wondering has nothing to do with documentation conventions. The javadoc shows methods. Methods have arguments. Arguments have types. The type is the first part of the argument, and the name of the argument is the second part. That's just the basic Java syntax of a method declaration. So obviously, `s` must be a CharSequence. Don't expect to find an explanation of the Java syntax in the javadoc. Use an introductory Java book or tutorial for that.

Comment: These sort of questions are made clearer by trying to use them in code in an IDE. Trying a few things can be much quicker than reading hours of documentation. Documentation is still needed, but some trial-and-error can be very useful also.

Comment: @Peter - good point...and I finally got an understanding of using the method with a combination of a program and documentation. Agreed that one cannot rely on one OR the other, they have to work in concert.

Comment: If you want an in depth understanding, nothing beats documentation. For everything else, nothing beats experience. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharSequence is an interface in java. Generally while going though the methods in javadocs if you see something that you don't understand try moving mouse over it. It will be having a help text to help you.
For example, in the link that you have provided if you move the cursor on CharSequence it will tell you that it is an interface in java.

your understanding of the doc will increase with your understanding of java.

Comment: Yep.. that's what I did. I just kept following links and trying things until I finally got something working. I've at least gotten THAT far in using the docs. :)

Comment: It would be more helpful if instead of simply reading the doc, you just try those code using any  JAVA IDE.

Comment: agreed; see my comment to Peter, above. :)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by a "literal value"? It (`CharSequence`) is the type of the parameter named `s`.

The syntax is to call `contains` on a string instance. You pass in a `CharSequence` (e.g., a `String`) and you get back a boolean indicating if the instance you're calling it on contains the value passed in:

```
String s = "foobar";
System.out.println(s.contains("ooba")); // true
System.out.println(s.contains("ohai")); // false
```

This has nothing to do with not understanding Javadocs, this is not understanding Java.

In this case, I'm not sure where the confusion lies, however. Assuming you know Java is an OOPL, and except for primitives, you call methods on instances (ignoring static methods for now), what's the problem? The `String` API shows that a string is-a `CharSequence`, the type taken by this method. The verbiage describes what the method does. Test code seems self-evident–but I'm a biased sample ;)

Since it's reasonably clear from the documentation standpoint, I have to assume it's an issue understanding the fundamental nature of Java. And you will *always* run into methods you've never seen before. And classes. And packages. And libraries. There are thousands of methods in the JDK alone, let alone Java EE, let alone the hundreds of other libraries used in any Java application of any size.

Trivial example; a very small project for work has 120+ dependencies. In those 120+ dependencies are 2500+ classes. In those 2500+ classes there are ~16k public properties (fields, methods, static values). This does not include the Java SE and Java EE APIs.

I'd guesstimate I've seen or used maybe one-thousandth of the project-specific APIs.

Comment: What I mean by a `literal` is that with my knowledge of Java, it may be possible for the statement to be `contains(CharSequence "ooba")` as if you were creating a value to compare on the fly. I don't know enough about Java to instinctively know that `CharSequence` (which was brand new to me) is an interface. But, I do know what to do *with* interefaces if I find one.

Comment: @dwwilson66 That's why I said it's not understanding Java, because you can't do that. It doesn't matter if it's an interface or a class--from the standpoint of the method, or the docs, it's not relevant. That's partially the point of interfaces: Since Java doesn't have multiple (implementation) inheritance, as long as something is-a `CharSequence`, you can pass it to the `contains` method.